# <Animated. view> is not get updated with component

Tags: react-native

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import {
  Animated,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native"
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage"
import styles from "./extras"
import Popup from "./Popup"

class EditProfile extends Component {
  state = { top: new Animated.Value(100) }
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Edit profile",
    drawerLabel: "Edit profile",
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: styles.secondaryColor,
            width: "80%",
            height: "22%",
            top: "25%",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignSelf: "center",
          }}
          onPress={() => this.setState({ alertpositon: 80 })}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: styles.secondaryColor, fontSize: 20 }}>
            Update
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Popup
          mode="Error"
          message="details incorrect"
          title="Error"
          textcolor={styles.secondaryColor}

        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default EditProfile
```

**Popup.js**

```
export default class Popup extends React.Component{


state={bgcolors:null,top:new Animated.Value(100)}




somefunc=()=>{


  console.log('function is working')
}

componentDidMount(){



}

render=()=>{

  console.log('sadas',this.props.mode)
  {if(this.props.mode=='warn'){
    console.log('dofucl'),


    this.state.bgcolors='#F5AC07'

  }
  else if (this.props.mode=='Error') {

      this.state.bgcolors='#D83C0A'
  }else if (this.props.mode=='good') {

      this.state.bgcolors='#0EBF07'
  }}

      Animated.timing(this.state.top, {
    toValue: 80,
    easing: Easing.back(),
    duration: 2000,
  }).start();
  console.log('tick');

  return(

    <Animated.View                 
      style={{width:'100%',
      height:'20%',
        position:'absolute',
      top:`${this.state.top._value}%`
             // Bind opacity to animated value
      }}
    >



<View style={{flexDirection:'column',width:'100%',
backgroundColor:this.state.bgcolors


,height:'100%',
justifyContent:'center'
}}>
<Text style={{alignSelf:'center',color:this.props.textcolor,position:'absolute',fontSize:15}}>{this.props.message}</Text>
<Text style={{color:this.props.textcolor,fontWeight:'700',fontSize:30}}>{this.props.title}</Text>

</View>

  </Animated.View>




);


}
}
```

When I try to run the code the app crashes with no error message, I don't know why it has do the snack bar like animation in the app but I don't what happening,

**Happened**
app crashed without no error message in the debugger

**expected behavior**
Snack bar like animation

**Noticed strange behavior:**
When executing any onclick method in **Edit profile.js** i can see the **Popup.js** updating its state

Comment: can you share the terminal error if possible ?

Comment: Also you are passing top `{ top: new Animated.Value(100) }`as props and manipulating it inside, which cannot be possible. You need to manipulate your animated value on the same component. So try manipulating the value on the same component like on **EditProfile** and then pass it as props. Let me know if it helps

Comment: This time it not crashing but instead it's not Animating  but i notice starnge behaviour that When executing any onclick method in Edit profile.js I can see the snack bar appears without animation @ShashankMalviya

Comment: Cool now its like you just need to animate your state value. Now write a onclick function to animate with below code.

`Animated.timing(this.state.top, {
    toValue: 80,
    easing: Easing.back(),
    duration: 2000,
  }).start();` 

Also can you keep this simple for now:

`top: this.state.top`

Comment: why in on click function I already included that in the render method @ShashankMalviya

Comment: See then on every re-render it will call the animation @shubhashchandru. you need to specify your expected condition for the animation to happen. And the way you are doing it is a very bad practice. Please understand. Avoid writing animations in render always. I just said onClick, you can do any function call you wanna do

Comment: it will be very kind if you edit the code , as iam beginnner !@ShashankMalviya

Comment: can you please tell me your development environment ?

Comment: "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4", @ShashankMalviya

Comment: Android or ios ?

Comment: android  enviroiment @ShashankMalviya

Comment: Am writing a code blindly have a look. Please Don't downvote. Ask me if you face any difficulties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import {
  Animated,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
Platform
} from "react-native"
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage"
import styles from "./extras"
import Popup from "./Popup"

export default class EditProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      topIos: new Animated.Value(0),
      topAndroid: new Animated.Value(0)
    }

  }
animateTop = () => {
      if(OS == 'ios'){
          Animated.timing(this.state.topIos, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 200,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: Platform.OS == 'ios' ? false : true
          }).start();
        } else {
          Animated.timing(this.state.topAndroid, {
            toValue: -(deviceHeight* 0.1), // deviceHeight =  Dimensions.get('window').height
            duration: 200,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: Platform.OS == 'ios' ? false : true
          }).start();
        }
      }
      else{
          Animated.timing(this.state.topAndroid, {
            toValue: deviceHeight* 0.1,
            duration: 200,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: Platform.OS == 'ios' ? false : true
          }).start();
          Animated.timing(this.state.topIos, {
            toValue: -(deviceHeight* 0.11),
            duration: 200,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: Platform.OS == 'ios' ? false : true
          }).start();
      }
  } 

render(){
return(
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: styles.secondaryColor,
        width: "80%",
        height: "22%",
        top: "25%",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignSelf: "center",
      }}
      onPress={() => this.animateTop}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: styles.secondaryColor, fontSize: 20 }}>
        Update
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <Popup
      mode="Error"
      message="details incorrect"
      title="Error"
      textcolor={styles.secondaryColor}
topIos = {this.state.topIos}
topAndroid = {this.state.topAndroid}
        />
      </View>
    )
    }
```

---

```
export default class Popup extends React.Component{
state={bgcolors:null}
render=()=>{
  {if(this.props.mode=='warn'){
    this.state.bgcolors='#F5AC07'
  }
  else if (this.props.mode=='Error') {
      this.state.bgcolors='#D83C0A'
  }else if (this.props.mode=='good') {
      this.state.bgcolors='#0EBF07'
  }}
  return(
    <Animated.View style={[Platform.OS == 'ios' ? { top: this.props.topIos} : {translateY : this.props.topAndroid}]}>
        <View  style={{flex : 1}}></View>
        </Animated.View>




);


}
}
```

Comment: As your see i edited my code , i just need a final clarification from you , that how can  execute animate func from edit profile ,i have tried ref in but its not working

Comment: I have updated the code, let me know if you can understand and implement it like this. Now what you have to do is do the opposite of animation. ` animateTop` function will only handle one side animation right now. Do the opposite y setting a state on clicking the button.

Comment: No friend , i suppose struct this code like a library so that , we dont want to use animtop() on every component , can't we do like that?

Comment: can understand friend Alerady or atleast?

Comment: Atleast, sorry it was typo.